# How to study this sequence $u_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+2k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Please is there any way to prove that sequence is increasing ?

I do: $u_{n+1}-u_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)+2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+2k}=\left[\frac{1}{n+3}+\frac{1}{n+5}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+3}\right]-\left[\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3n}\right]$

i don't know how to continue

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: i want to prove that it is increasing

Comment: Well, all of the terms are positive, so ...

Comment: @MattiP. it can be positif and decreasing !

Comment: @MattiP. Each term also depends on $n$ though

Comment: try with $u_{n+2}-u_n$

Comment: @Damien i found $\frac{1}{3n+2}+\frac{1}{3n+3}+\frac{1}{3n+6}-\frac{1}{n+2}$

Comment: @Vrouvrou it's not hard to prove that it's positive

Comment: but monotonicity is between two consecutive terms @Damien

Comment: That's a good start but I don't know how to go further.. :(.

Comment: But, it's not hard to prove that $u_n$ is convex ($u_{n+2}-2u_{n+1}+u_n \geq 0$)

Comment: what do you think if. I do the change of variable$K=2k$then $u_n=\sum_{K=1/2}^{n/2} \frac{1}{n+K}$ no ? @Damien

Comment: @Damien what we can do with convexity?

Comment: @Vrouvrou this would mean that $u_{n+1}-u_{n}$ is increasing, thus always positive

Comment: @Damienhow you do to get $u_{n+2}-2u_{n+1}+u_n \geq 0$ ? from where  this formula?

Comment: First, prove $1/(n+2+2k) - 2/(n+1+2k) + 1/(n+2k)\geq 0$ for any n,k, then prove that the remainder of the sum is also $\geq 0$

Comment: Sorry, this is exactly the opposite, $u_{n+1}-u_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: I've modified TeX *spaces*. If you had difficulties due to the display of my *Answer* below, now you have another chance, now it has been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

We can write
$$u_n = \int \limits_0^1 (x^{n+1} + x^{n+3} + \cdots + x^{3n-1}) dx = \int \limits_0^1 x^{n+1} \left( \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^2} \right) dx.$$
Now, replace $n$ by a continuous variable $t$ and try to prove that $u_t$ is monotonous (Hint: Differentiate with respect to $t$).

Comment: How do you relate your powers to the OP's question?

Comment: If you integrate term by term, you will get $\frac{1}{n+2}, \frac{1}{n+4}$ and so on. For instance, $\int x^{n+1} dx = x^{n+2}/(n+2)$ and putting the limits $0$ and $1$ will give you $1/(n+2)$.

Comment: yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OP, a good start:

$$u_{n+1}-u_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(n+1)+2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+2k}$$

Let's continue.  First,

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n
    \frac 1{(n+2\!\cdot\! k-\frac 12)
  \cdot(n+2\!\cdot\!k+\frac 32)}\,
    \, =\,\, \frac 12\cdot\left(
\, \frac 1{n+2-\frac 12}\, -\, \frac 1{3\cdot n+\frac 32}
\right) $$
$$ =\, \frac 1{2\cdot n+3}\, -\, \frac 1{6\cdot n+3} $$

Next,

$$ u_{n+1}-u_n\quad =\quad \frac 1{3n+3}\,\, -\,
 \, \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{(n+2\cdot k)
                \cdot(n+2\!\cdot\!k+1)} $$

$$ =\,\, \frac 1{3n+3}\,\, -\,\, \left(
\frac 1{2\cdot n+3}\, -\, \frac 1{6\cdot n+3}\right)\, + $$
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n
    \frac 1{(n+2\!\cdot\! k-\frac 12)
  \cdot(n+2\!\cdot\!k+\frac 32)}
    \, -\, \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{(n+2\cdot k)
                \cdot(n+2\!\cdot\!k+1)}   $$

$$ =\,\, \frac 1{3n+3}\,\, -\,\, \left(
\frac 1{2\cdot n+3}\, -\, \frac 1{6\cdot n+3}\right)\, + $$
$$ \frac 34\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1
{(n+2\!\cdot\! k-\frac 12)\cdot(n+2\!\cdot\!k+\frac 32)
   \cdot(n+2\cdot k)\cdot(n+2\!\cdot\!k+1)} $$

$$ >\,\, \frac 1{3n+3}\,\, -\,\, \left(
\frac 1{2\cdot n+3}\, -\, \frac 1{6\cdot n+3}\right)\ =
$$  $$ \frac{(2\!\cdot\! n+1)\!\cdot\!(2\!\cdot\! n+3)
 + (n+1)\!\cdot\!(2\!\cdot\! n+3) -
    3\!\cdot\!(n+1)\!\cdot\!(2\!\cdot\! n+1)}
{3\cdot(n+1)\cdot(2\cdot n+1)\cdot(2\cdot n+3)} 
$$  $$ =\, \frac{4\cdot n+3}
{3\cdot(n+1)\cdot(2\cdot n+1)\cdot(2\cdot n+3)} $$

This means that the following theorem holds,

**Theorem**

$$ \forall_{n=1\, 2\, \ldots}\quad u_n<u_{n+1} $$

*Great!*

Comment: No more integrals (nor derivatives). Some explicit detailed computations. I wanted to play it safe, and I wanted everybody to have an easy time to verify my proof.

Comment: Thanks, I'll delete the answer, for now, not to raise confusion.

Comment: @dfnu, you're very nice and kind, like a **true** mathematician. In the past, I had to remove my answers on MO more than once (on one occasions they even encouraged me to keep it since it introduced a good idea but I didn't want anything of it when it was incorrect).

Comment: Thanks for appreciation. At least I have got  a necessary condition to be a mathematician... which I am not. Only here to learn. And as a plus: I earned a "disciplined" badge :)

Comment: Very nice trick and solution! Is it an usual trick to use a telescping sum to obtain am effective bound? It is a plesure to see this great solutions here. Please continue to partecipate when you can. Bye

Comment: @user, thank you for your kind words (I don't deserve so much, thus, I even feel embarrassed). Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The early original OP's question was *how to study this sequence*.

You could think in terms of the logarithmic function. Already, the crudest approximation of $\ \frac 1{m+2\cdot k}\ $ gives about

$$ \frac 12\cdot\log\frac{m+2\cdot k+2}{m+2\cdot k} $$

Now you can approximate (crudely)
$\ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{n+2\cdot k}.\ $ You get roughly

$$ \frac 12\cdot\log\left(\frac{3\cdot n+2}{n+2}\right) $$

The above expression increases (slowly; but I can't make any claim yet about the actual OP's series), and you may expect that the limit will slowly shoot up to reach $\ \frac{\log(3)}2.$

Of course, one needs to be more careful than this. One should use two-sided estimates, and one may enjoy finer approximations of
 $\ \log.$

> **Remark** Axioms
>
> - 1. $ \qquad\qquad \log(1)=0;$
> - 2. $\ \,\forall_{x\ y>0}\quad \log(x\cdot y)\ = \log(x)+\log(y); $
> - 3. $\ \,\forall_{x>-1}\quad \log(1+x)\ \le\ x; $
>
> characterize logarithm. This means that all sophisticated logarithmic
>   inequalities can be derived from the above one simple inequality (with the help of the other two axioms).

For instance:

$$ -\log(1+x)\ =\ \log\left(\frac 1{1+x}\right)\ =
\ \log\left(1-\frac x{1+x}\right)
\ \le\ \frac{-x}{1+x} $$

This, together with axiom 3, gives:

$$ \forall_{x>-1}\quad \frac x{1+x} \le\ \log(1+x)\ \le\ x $$

> Now, one gets logarithmic approximations on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general and assuming you know about harmonic numbers
$$u_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+ak}=\frac 1a\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\frac n a+k}=\frac 1a\left(H_{n+\frac{n}{a}}-H_{\frac{n}{a}} \right)$$ Now, at least for large values of $n$, using the asymptotics
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+\frac{1}{120
   p^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^6}\right)$$ apply it and continue with Taylor series to get
$$u_{n+1}-u_n=\frac{a}{2 (a+1) n^2}-\frac{a(a^2+5 a+3)}{6 (a+1)^2
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$